# 410 generated url with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, http-status-code-401

i have list of url pattern similar like this

```
https://www.web.com/?route=affiliate/register&amp
https://www.web.com/?route=account/edit&amp
https://www.web.com/index.php?route=affiliate/register&amp
https://www.web.com/index.php?route=account/edit&amp
https://www.web.com/?route=product/manufacturer/productmanufacturer_id
https://www.web.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/productmanufacturer_id
```

any url variation after `index.php` are not being used anymore

i'd like to ask some help in order properly **set anything after** `index.php` as 410 since index.php are still in used several pages

---edit---

my default index page are using default ( `index.php`,`index.html`,`index.htm`)

so using ravi htaccess code this url are still return 200 OK (doesn't works)

```
https://www.web.com/?route=affiliate/register&amp
https://www.web.com/?route=account/edit&amp
```

And only works on this url variation

```
https://www.web.com/index.php?route=affiliate/register&amp
https://www.web.com/index.php?route=account/edit&amp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```